# How to create lightbox popup form without using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

**Here is my code:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () { //on clicking the link above
        $(this).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"100%",scrolling:false});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>External Form</h3>
<a href="https://ss88.wufoo.com/forms/rmndx1a0zzpe4m/" id="test">Please fill out my form.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it works fine, but i need without using iframe for some further features.

Can anybody help me?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean a form in pop box. [like this](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/) Click on View Demo

Comment: Above code works fine, but i used iframe, so i want without using iframe.

Comment: You can go with [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download). And use popup like [**bootstarp modal**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) CSS and JS styling framework. You can [download](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) it from here. [Refer the files and folder structure](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included-precompiled).

Now you can copy `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-theme.css`, then paste it in your project like

- Myproject

  - CSS

    - bootstrap.css
    - bootstrap-theme.css
  - JS

    - bootstrap.js
  - demo.html

Now this your moderated **demo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 <script src="JS/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap-theme.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

</head>
<body>
   <h3>External Form</h3>
       <a id="test" href="javascript:void(0);" 
          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myWufooModal">
           Please fill out my form.
       </a>
   <div class="modal fade" id="myWufooModal" tabindex="-1" 
        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <a href="https://ss88.wufoo.com/forms/rmndx1a0zzpe4m/" id="test">
               </div>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```